# Laravel - Get data from Ajax Post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to upload images with ajax. I convert the image to a base64 string. Posting the data works, but how do I get it on the server *(I'm using Laravel 5.4)*? I can do `$request->all()` what gives me an array with all the images base64 strings combined. I cannot do anything with that because whatever I do with that array will result in a 500 error.

This is my script to convert the images and post them.

```
let queue = [];
function addFile(input) {
    let files = input.files,
        j = files.length,
        file;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            $('#upload-InnerPanel').append(
                "<div class='upload-ItemPanel'><img class='upload-ImagePreview' src='" + e.target.result + "' > </div>");
            queue.push(reader.result);
        };
        file = files[i];
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

$('#upload-ButtonSelect').on("click" , function () {
    $('#upload-UploadInput').click();
});

$('#upload-UploadInput').change(function () {
    addFile(this);
});

$('#upload-ButtonUpload').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/upload",
        type: "POST",
        data: queue,
        processData: false,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            let err = xhr.responseText;
            //console.log(err);
            $('#upload-InnerPanel').append("<iframe width='600' height='500' src='" + err +"'> </iframe>")
        },
        success: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

});
```

This is my controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{

    return var_dump($request->all());
}
```

That works, sort of, because My response is one long base64 in an array with just 1 item. Even if I add multiple images I just get one item in the array instead of three. It now combines them all in to one. Also, as I said. I cannot do anything with that array what does not result in a 500 error.

So my question is:

How do I get it to work so I can post multiple items instead of one and get the data on the backend?

Comment: Can you share the `$request->all()` output?

Comment: Can please share the input file taken line from the html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add each file as a new input on your form, so that you have them separately on the back end.

In your `addFile` Javascript, instead of `queue.push(reader.result)`, append a hidden input with the results:

```
reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    // ... your code
    // Update the form selector to suit your form
    $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="' + reader.result + '">');
};
```

Then in your ajax form submission:

```
$('#upload-ButtonUpload').click(function () {

    // Again update the form selector to suit your form
    var data = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/upload",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        // ... etc
```